# How to resolve "Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" using Dropbox for Android in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, dropbox, dropbox-api

I follow the example exactly:

```
protected async override void OnStart ()
{
    base.OnStart ();
    AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(AppKey, AppSecret);
    AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
    dropboxApi = new DropboxAPI (session);
    (DropboxApi.Session as AndroidAuthSession).StartOAuth2Authentication (this);
}
```

but I get the error:

```
Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Dropbox.CoreApi.Android.DropboxApi.Session.get' (CS0120)
```

On the following line :

```
 (DropboxApi.Session as AndroidAuthSession).StartOAuth2Authentication (this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
(DropboxApi.Session as AndroidAuthSession)
```

Should be:

```
(dropboxApi.Session as AndroidAuthSession)
```

Notice the capital D referencing the class instead of the instance.